# create one pdf with data from all the rotations of a loop

Tags: r, pdf, for-loop

I have the following loop

```
for (chr in paste('chr',c(seq(1,22),'X','Y'),sep='')){
.
.
pdf(sprintf ('anna.%s.pdf',chr), paper='a4')
plot(exp,control,xlim=c(0,400),ylim=c(0,400),pch=20,col='black',main='Tiles',xlab='exp',ylab 'Control')
dev.off()

write.table(exp.sorted,file="list.txt",append = TRUE ,quote = FALSE,col.names =FALSE,row.names=TRUE,sep="\t")
}
```

with the current code the loop will make 24 pdfs for anna and each one will have the data from ONE rotation of the loop

what i need is to have only one anna.pdf and in graph that creates to add in the data of every rotation of the loop. NOT to erase the previous data of each rotation of the loop, but just to add the data from every loop to have one total graph which will contain the data from all the rotations of the loop.

Pretty much what I do with the append=TRUE when i create the table and have one list.txt where the loop just adds the data from each rotation

thank you in advance

best regards
Anna

PS:

so, if i say the following is ok?

```
for (chr in c(paste('chr',seq(1,22),sep=''),'chrX','chrY')){ 
anna1<-exp
anna2<-control
 .
.
.
.
pdf('anna.pdf', paper='a4')
for (chr in paste('chr',c(seq(1,22),'X','Y'),sep='')){
if(!PLOT){
  plot(exp,control,xlim=c(0,400),ylim=c(0,400),   
   pch=20,col='black',main='Tiles',xlab='exp',ylab 'Control')
   PLOT <- TRUE
} else {
   lines(names(control.table), log10(control.table), col="blue")
}
legend('topright', legend=c('ChIP', 'Control'), col=c('red','blue'), lwd=1)
}
dev.off()
.
.
.
pdf('anna.enriched.pdf',paper='a4')
for (chr in paste('chr',c(seq(1,22),'X','Y'),sep='')){
plot(exp.peaks,control.peaks,xlim=c(0,400),ylim=c(0,400),pch=20,col='black')
}
dev.off()


}
```

which of these two pdfs is correct? both scripts are correct?

thank you

best regards
Anna

Answer (score 0):

You can add data to an existing plot using the points(...) or lines(...) functions.
Therefore you will have to create the plot in the first iteration.

e.g. something like this

```
PLOT <- FALSE
pdf('anna.pdf', paper='a4')
for (chr in paste('chr',c(seq(1,22),'X','Y'),sep='')){
    if(!PLOT){
      plot(exp,control,xlim=c(0,400),ylim=c(0,400),   
       pch=20,col='black',main='Tiles',xlab='exp',ylab 'Control')
       PLOT <- TRUE
    } else {
       points(exp,control, ...)
    }
}
dev.off()
```